# pytorch how to select channels by mask?

Tags: python-3.x, pytorch

I want to know how do I select channels by the mask in Pytorch.
[channel1 channel2 channel3 channel4] x [1,0,0,1] --> [channel1,channel4]
I tried torch.masked_select() and it did't work.

if the input has a shape like `[B,C,H,W]` the output's shape should be `[B,masked_C,H,W]`,

```py
import torch
from torch import nn
input = torch.randn((1,5,3,3))
pool = nn.AdaptiveAvgPool2d(1)
w = torch.sigmoid(pool(input)).view(1,-1)
mask = torch.gt(w,0.5)
print(input)
print(w)
print(mask)
```

the output is as following:

```py
tensor([[[[ 0.9129, -0.9763,  1.4460],
          [ 0.3608,  0.5561, -1.4612],
          [ 1.4953, -1.2474,  0.4069]],

         [[-0.9121,  0.1261,  0.4661],
          [-1.1624, -1.0266, -1.5419],
          [ 1.0644,  1.0039, -0.4022]],

         [[-1.8454, -0.2150,  2.3703],
          [ 0.5224,  0.3366,  1.7545],
          [-0.4624,  1.2639,  1.8032]],

         [[-1.1558, -1.9985, -1.1336],
          [-0.4400, -0.2092,  0.0677],
          [-0.4172, -0.3614, -1.3193]],

         [[-0.9441, -0.2944,  0.3381],
          [ 1.6562, -0.5623,  0.0599],
          [ 0.7229,  0.0472, -0.5122]]]])
tensor([[0.5414, 0.4341, 0.6489, 0.3156, 0.5142]])
tensor([[1, 0, 1, 0, 1]], dtype=torch.uint8)
```

the result I want is like this:

```py
tensor([[[[ 0.9129, -0.9763,  1.4460],
          [ 0.3608,  0.5561, -1.4612],
          [ 1.4953, -1.2474,  0.4069]],

         [[-1.8454, -0.2150,  2.3703],
          [ 0.5224,  0.3366,  1.7545],
          [-0.4624,  1.2639,  1.8032]],

         [[-0.9441, -0.2944,  0.3381],
          [ 1.6562, -0.5623,  0.0599],
          [ 0.7229,  0.0472, -0.5122]]]])
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, please provide the **error** so that we can help you.

Comment: Can you add the desired shapes of the tensors?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can simply do:

```py
input[mask]
```

Btw. you don't need to call `sigmoid` and then `.gt(0.5)`. You can directly do `.gt(0.0)` without calling the sigmoid.

Comment: thanks for your answer, I tried `input[mask]`, however, the result's shape is not I want.
if the input has a shape like `[B,C,H,W]` the output's shape should be `[B,masked_C,H,W]`, `input[mask]` gives a shape of `[masked_C,H,W]`